# Android 4 source: compising layers

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm looking for the place in code where Android OS performs layer composition. Really interesting how is it done for native OpenGL|ES application - it renders, swaps buffer in standard way, but somehow rendered picture composed with underlying - live wallpaper, for example. Where is in the Android source such code?

I really can't understand, how Android handles native app draws into with `eglSwapBuffers`.

Any article for composing and/or graphical engine are welcome. Just for clarity - how does Android compose native OpenGL|ES output with system's?